# Vertical forest diagram in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using the [`forest`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package in TeX:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt,multi]{standalone}

\usepackage{forest,array}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}p{#1}}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
  if level=0{align=center}{% allow multi-line text and set alignment
    align={@{}C{45mm}@{}},
  },
  draw,
  font=\sffamily\bfseries,
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5mm) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
  parent anchor=south,
  child anchor=north,
  l sep=10mm,
  tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
  edge={ultra thick, rounded corners=2pt},
  inner color=white,
  outer color=white,
  rounded corners=2pt,
  drop shadow,
}
[UML Diagram
  [Structure Diagram
    [Class Diagram]
    [Object Diagram]
    [Package Diagram]
    [Component Diagram]
    [Composite Structure Diagram]
    [Deployment Diagram]
    [Profile Diagram]
  ]
  [Behaviour Diagram
    [Use Case Diagram]
    [Activity Diagram]
    [State Machine Diagram]
    [Interaction Diagram
        [Sequence Diagram]
        [Communication Diagram]
        [Interaction Overview Diagram]
        [Timing Diagram]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

This code produces

[image]

I like using `forest` but with this kind of data it just doesn't work well. I need to tranpose/flip/rotate the diagram so it uses the length instead of the width of the page. So, instead of having the nodes next to each other, I need them underneath each other.

Can I do something smart in the `forest` package to flip it? I have searched for examples in the documentation but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Is this for a A4 page? Landscape or portrait?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the key `grow=east` and then change some things to accommodate this:

- parent and child anchor
- edge label computation

I also changed the coloring to `fill=white` because your options made the nodes look grey.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt,multi]{standalone}

\usepackage{forest,array}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}p{#1}}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
  if level=0{align=center}{% allow multi-line text and set alignment
    align={@{}C{45mm}@{}},
  },
  grow=east,
  draw,
  font=\sffamily\bfseries,
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(5mm,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
  parent anchor=east,
  child anchor=west,
  l sep=10mm,
  tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
  edge={ultra thick, rounded corners=2pt},
  fill=white,
  rounded corners=2pt,
  drop shadow,
}
[UML Diagram
  [Structure Diagram
    [Class Diagram]
    [Object Diagram]
    [Package Diagram]
    [Component Diagram]
    [Composite Structure Diagram]
    [Deployment Diagram]
    [Profile Diagram]
  ]
  [Behaviour Diagram
    [Use Case Diagram]
    [Activity Diagram]
    [State Machine Diagram]
    [Interaction Diagram
        [Sequence Diagram]
        [Communication Diagram]
        [Interaction Overview Diagram]
        [Timing Diagram]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Jamgreen If this solves the problem/question for your, please accept this answer by clicking on the check mark on the top left of the post :)

Comment: @Alenanno please see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600303/making-forrest-tree-fit-in-2-column-journals)