# How to draw a vertical hierarchical diagram using Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am investigating the acquisition history of a company, then I need to draw a hierarchical illustration diagram, it's not so-called flowchart, but exactly like this: 
[image]

And then here I tried some Tikz code, and I found that is a "mission impossible":

```
\begin{figure}[H]
%   \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}%[xscale=2,yscale=2]
%    \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (15,-21);
    \node[draw=none] (a) at (-1,0) {Medtronic};
    \node[draw=none] (b) at (-1,-.5) {\small Ardian Inc};
    \draw[-] (0,0) -- (.5,0);
    \draw[-] (0,-.5) -- (.5,-.5);
    \draw[-] (0.5,0) -- (0.5,-.5);
    \draw[-] (0.5,-.25) -- (1.5,-.25);
    \draw[-] (1.5,-.25) -- (1.5,-1);
    \node[draw=none] at (-.7,-1) {\small Osteotech Inc};
    \draw[-] (0.5,-1) -- (1.5,-1);
    \draw[-] (1.5,-.625) -- (2,-.625);
    \draw[-] (2,-.625) -- (2,-1.5);
    \draw[-] (2,-1.5) -- (1,-1.5);
    \node[draw=none] at (-.1,-1.5) {\small ATS medical};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and for this long code, I got the following:

[image]

then I lost my patience, noooo, that's not the right way to do this job, figuring out every each coordinate of points/lines gonna be a dumb way...

Do you know any methods/ways/packages to tikz generate this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware of the forest package? E.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250088/121799) achieves something that IMHO closely resembles your desired output.

Comment: Yes, @marmot that looks similar, but it's kind of hard to apply "forest" package to my own article (I m working on it), and the biggest problem is that when the forest is too long, it exceeds the right margin of the page.

Comment: OK, I see. I think it will be easy to do your figure with a simple loop, but what prevents people like me from coding it is the large number of texts one would need to type from your screenshot. I guess if you provide it, you'll get an answer soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, something without trees then. I reproduce your diagram except that I did not punch in the text, so I keep repeating the text of the top node. **UPDATE**: Corrected `every two node part` and `every one node part` and added `\nodepart{one}`, big thanks to wcharging!

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}
\tikzset{medi/.style={xshift=-5mm,anchor=west,rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2,
rectangle split part align={left,left},%
font=\sffamily},
every two node part/.style={font=\sffamily\small,align=left},
every one node part/.style={font=\sffamily,align=left},
node distance=5mm and 5mm}
\newcommand{\Connect}[3][]{%
\draw[] (X-#2) -- ++(-0.8cm,0) |- (#3.west) coordinate[pos=0.1] (X-#3);}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[medi] (1) {\nodepart{one}Meditronic \nodepart{two} (Founded 1949)};
\node[medi,below=of 1,xshift=-3mm] (2) {\nodepart{one}Meditronic \nodepart{two} (Founded 1949)};
\node[medi,below=of 2,xshift=-3mm] (3) {\nodepart{one}Meditronic \nodepart{two} (Founded 1949)};
\node[medi,below=of 3,xshift=-3mm] (4) {\nodepart{one}Meditronic \nodepart{two} (Founded 1949)};
\node[medi,below=of 4,xshift=-3mm] (5) {\nodepart{one}Meditronic \nodepart{two} (Founded 1949)};
\node[medi,below=of 5,xshift=-3mm] (6) {\nodepart{one}Meditronic \nodepart{two} (Founded 1949)};
\node[medi,below=of 6,xshift=-3mm] (7) {\nodepart{one}Meditronic \nodepart{two} (Founded 1949)};
\node[medi,below=of 7,xshift=-3mm] (8) {\nodepart{one}Meditronic \nodepart{two} (Founded 1949)};
\node[medi,below=of 8,xshift=-3mm] (9) {\nodepart{one}Meditronic \nodepart{two} (Founded 1949)};
\node[medi,below=of 9,xshift=-3mm] (10) {\nodepart{one}Meditronic \nodepart{two} (Founded 1949)};
\node[medi,below=of 10,xshift=-3mm] (11) {\nodepart{one}Meditronic \nodepart{two} (Founded 1949)};
\node[medi,below=of 11,xshift=-3mm] (12) {\nodepart{one}Meditronic \nodepart{two} (Founded 1949)};
\node[medi,below=of 12,xshift=-3mm] (13) {\nodepart{one}Meditronic \nodepart{two} (Founded 1949)};
\draw (1.west) -- ++(-1.2cm,0) |- (2.west) coordinate[pos=0.22] (X-2);
\foreach \Y [evaluate={\X=int(\Y-1)}] in {3,...,13}
{\Connect{\X}{\Y}}
\draw (X-13) -- ++(-0.5cm,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Than you so much marmot!

Comment: You can probably use a single `\foreach` for drawing the nodes and the lines, in place of copy/paste for the nodes.

Comment: This is almost right: `every {lower,upper} node part` should be `every {two,text} node part`, respectively. Currently, your styles there do nothing (as you can note most easily by changing your global `font=\sffamily` to `font=\rmfamily` or similar).

Comment: (Also, consider a semantic `\newcommand*{\company}[2]{#1 \nodepart{two} (#2)}`. :-) )

Comment: @Kpym I know but I decided against it. Mainly because I cannot know what the OP ultimately will put in these nodes. In her or his screenshots there are citations and so on, `\foreach` can give trouble if there are commas and the like. IMHO your suggestion (and `\newcommand`) makes really sense if one has some parameters that one wants to be able to adjust globally. Here the code is set up that this does not happen, these directives are all in the styles.

Comment: @marmot: This technically works now, but your `every one node part` is still having no effect. The correct name is `every text node part`. It works because the styles in that group don't actually change anything against the global styles, but if you changed to `every one node part={color=red}` then you would see that, in fact, nothing is red. You should either make the styles `every text node part`, or make the nodes like `\nodepart{one} Medtronic \nodepart{two} (Founded 1949)}`, or just delete the extraneous styles. :-)

Comment: @marmot Excellent!! I like your code.