# Unique level color in vertical forest diagram in tikz

Tags: forest

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt,multi]{standalone}

    \usepackage{forest,array}

    \usetikzlibrary{shadows}

    \begin{document}

    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}p{#1}}

    \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      if level=0{align=center}{% allow multi-line text and set alignment
        align={@{}C{45mm}@{}},
      },
      grow=east,
      draw,
      font=\sffamily\bfseries,
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(5mm,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      },
      parent anchor=east,
      child anchor=west,
      l sep=10mm,
      tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
      edge={ultra thick, rounded corners=2pt},
      fill=white,
      rounded corners=2pt,
      drop shadow,
    }
    [UML Diagram
      [Structure Diagram
        [Class Diagram]
        [Object Diagram]
        [Package Diagram]
        [Component Diagram]
        [Composite Structure Diagram]
        [Deployment Diagram]
        [Profile Diagram]
      ]
      [Behaviour Diagram
        [Use Case Diagram]
        [Activity Diagram]
        [State Machine Diagram]
        [Interaction Diagram
            [Sequence Diagram]
            [Communication Diagram]
            [Interaction Overview Diagram]
            [Timing Diagram]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    \end{forest}

    \end{document}
```

How to assign a unique colour/fill to Parent (level 1)  and grandchild (level 2).

> Credits [Vertical forest diagram in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250087/vertical-forest-diagram-in-tikz)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

For this you only need add to `for tree={...}` options

```
      if level=1{fill=blue!30}{if level=3{fill=red!30}{}},
```

Comment: Thanks. I am new to Tex. How to fill/colour an individual branch in a level? Say I want to assign distant colours to "Structure Diagram" and "Behaviour Diagram"...

Comment: `[Structure Diagram,fill=red`, `[Behavior Diagram, fill=red`. Please edit your question and make your question clear.