# Making Forest Fit in 2 Column Journals

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

So I have a forrest similar to [Vertical Forrest](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250087/vertical-forest-diagram-in-tikz). I am interested in fitting this to two column journal document with following class. But the forrest overflows in second column out of the page. Is there any way to make it fit in one of the columns? Also I want to remove the boxes and want to have plain text instead.

The latex template for the document can be found [here](http://www.icinco.org/Templates.aspx)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside, multi, tikz]{article}

\usepackage{apalike}

\usepackage{forest,array}

\usepackage{SCITEPRESS}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}p{#1}}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
  if level=0{align=center}{% allow multi-line text and set alignment
    align={@{}C{45mm}@{}},
  },
  grow=east,
  draw,
  font=\sffamily\bfseries,
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(5mm,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
  parent anchor=east,
  child anchor=west,
  l sep=10mm,
  tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
  edge={ultra thick, rounded corners=2pt},
  fill=white,
  rounded corners=2pt,
  drop shadow,
}
[UML Diagram
  [Structure Diagram
    [Class Diagram]
    [Object Diagram]
    [Package Diagram]
    [Component Diagram]
    [Composite Structure Diagram]
    [Deployment Diagram]
    [Profile Diagram]
  ]
  [Behaviour Diagram
    [Use Case Diagram]
    [Activity Diagram]
    [State Machine Diagram]
    [Interaction Diagram
        [Sequence Diagram]
        [Communication Diagram]
        [Interaction Overview Diagram]
        [Timing Diagram]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example only has one column, but anyways, will something as simple as changing `C{45mm}` to e.g. `C{25mm}` work?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. it has no effect unfortunately.

Comment: If I run your example as is, I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/625yf.png. If I change the 45mm to 25mm I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tFuc.png Do you not get that?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. no actually even changing to 2mm has no effect. Perhaps because the journal uses `\usepackage{SCITEPRESS}`

Comment: And where can that package be found? Please also edit the example so it reflects what you're actually using.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the post with the link of the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can squeeze it into a single column by reducing the font size and the separation between levels. See code below.

Another option might be to put the tree in a  `figure*` environment, which spans both columns, and add a caption and label, which you can `\ref` elsewhere. Then all you need to do is modify the aforementioned width of the `C` columns.

You get boxes because you've added `draw` to the tree options, as well as `drop shadow`. Remove those, and you may as well remove the fill and rounded corners as well.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside, multi, tikz]{article}

\usepackage{apalike}

\usepackage{forest,array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}p{#1}}

\usepackage{SCITEPRESS}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{center}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
  align=center,
  minimum width=13.5mm,
  grow=east,
%  draw, % <-- removed
  font=\sffamily\bfseries\scriptsize, % <-- smaller font
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(2mm,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};  % <-- shorter edge
  },
  parent anchor=east,
  child anchor=west,
  l sep=4mm, % <-- less space
  tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
  edge={ultra thick, rounded corners=2pt},
%  fill=white, % <-- removed
%  rounded corners=2pt, % <-- removed
% drop shadow, % <-- removed
}
[UML\\Diagram
  [Structure\\Diagram
    [Class\\Diagram]
    [Object\\Diagram]
    [Package\\Diagram]
    [Component\\Diagram]
    [Composite\\Structure\\Diagram]
    [Deployment\\Diagram]
    [Profile\\Diagram]
  ]
  [Behaviour\\Diagram
    [Use Case\\Diagram]
    [Activity\\Diagram]
    [State\\Machine\\Diagram]
    [Interaction\\Diagram
        [Sequence\\Diagram]
        [Communication\\Diagram]
        [Interaction\\Overview\\Diagram]
        [Timing\\Diagram]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{center}
\lipsum

\begin{figure*}
\centering
\begin{forest}
for tree={
  if level=0{align=center}{% allow multi-line text and set alignment
    align={@{}C{30mm}@{}}, % <---only changed this
  },
  grow=east,
  font=\sffamily\bfseries,
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(5mm,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
  parent anchor=east,
  child anchor=west,
  l sep=10mm,
  tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
  edge={ultra thick, rounded corners=2pt},
}
[UML Diagram
  [Structure Diagram
    [Class Diagram]
    [Object Diagram]
    [Package Diagram]
    [Component Diagram]
    [Composite Structure Diagram]
    [Deployment Diagram]
    [Profile Diagram]
  ]
  [Behaviour Diagram
    [Use Case Diagram]
    [Activity Diagram]
    [State Machine Diagram]
    [Interaction Diagram
        [Sequence Diagram]
        [Communication Diagram]
        [Interaction Overview Diagram]
        [Timing Diagram]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\caption{...}
\label{foo}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image: tree fitting in a single column]

[image: tree in figure*]

Comment: Alright, this works. I am interested in the first type as it does barely fit in the column. But if the tree grows a little more east wards then it overflows to other page.

Comment: @user0193 Not entirely sure what you mean. If it becomes wider it will eventually go into either the other column or the margin, and out of the page, but not into the next page.

Comment: Opps I have a typo. I meant next column, not next page. Anyways it works for now. Thanks.